# NPM Run Dev Connects Then Fails

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js13

When creating a nextJS project in Visual Studio code,  running the command 'npm run dev' the terminal connects and then returns to the prompt. In looking at the local server, the browser states that it can not connect.[Terminal result and silent failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATOek.png)

I tried to do the following (no specific order):

- Made a new project, behavior was present in both.
- Used a terminal outside of VS code.
- Verified that the node is correct based on this post: [https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/11nno8b/npm_run_dev_runs_for_a_second_then_exits_for_no/](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Reinstalled npm within the project by following these steps:

```
stop your dev server (ctrl+c)
delete .next folder in your project's root folder.
delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file too.
run npm install
run npm run dev
```

- verified that `npm run build` and `npm run start` both worked.
- Packagelock.json:
  [Packagelock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocVgE.png)

Comment: Share the full error as code in the question (and not as screenshot)

Comment: hey Robin, sorry if not clear, but there is not an error code that is being thrown in the terminal.

Comment: If you have something from browser (like UI, console, network calls), please add that to question

Comment: the connection to the localhost appears to be connecting and then failing. Screen shot linked here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATOek.png

Comment: Where do you see this "failing" in the screenshot?